# Append to protected file without creating a new line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script that, among other things, appends the string " fastboot noswap ro" to the end of /boot/cmdline.txt.

At first I was trying `sudo echo " fastboot noswap ro" >> /boot/cmdline.txt` but was getting permission denied.

I learned that for protected files, the best way to do it is `echo ' fastboot noswap ro' | sudo tee -a /boot/cmdline.txt`.

That works, but it makes it start on a new line. I can't find anything in the tee man page about appending without inserting a new line.

How can I append to this protected file without creating a new line?

Comment: Using `tee` I doubt you can. How about doing `echo "..." >> ...` in a sub shell and doing sudo on the whole subshell ?

Comment: if your file already has newline at the end you would have to delete it first

Comment: @AlbinPaul, it doesn't. I saw if I repeated that command multiple times, it automatically inserts a line break.

Comment: @John3136, so my first attempt used `echo "..." >> ...`, but I'm not following "in a sub shell and doing sudo on the whole subshell".

Comment: `echo` automatically inserts line break _after_ the text, so that would be what you would be seeing in the repeated application of your command. The file itself already has a newline, because `echo` does not insert a line break _before_ the text and `tee` does not add newlines at all, so the only explanation for it to be there is to have existed previously to your command (also, because UNIX defines a line as sequence of characters terminating in a newline, so a text file that does not end in a newline is defective, from UNIX point of view).

Comment: Not at a linux box right now to check, but something like sudo "(echo ... >> file)" - you may need to escape the () or something, as I said, can't check right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The newline is already there, you can't remove things by appending.

Instead, you would have to replace the content of the file with the changed line.

The easiest way to do so would likely be `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/$/ fastboot noswap ro/' /boot/cmdline.txt
```

or `paste`:

```
paste /boot/cmdline.txt <(echo fastboot noswap ro) | sudo tee /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo -n ' fastboot noswap ro' | sudo tee -a /boot/cmdline.txt
```

> man echo says

```
    Options:
      -n    do not append a newline
```